# PHP & MySQL: Query to "sum" 2 rows from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table:

```
+------------+-------+------------+-----------+
| date       | time  | custom_id  | Number    |
+------------+-------+------------+-----------+
| 01/17/2014 | 00:00 | ABC123     | 15        |
| 01/17/2014 | 00:00 | HEY567     | 25        |
| 01/17/2014 | 00:30 | ABC123     | 17        |
| 01/17/2014 | 00:30 | HEY567     | 28        |
| 01/17/2014 | 01:00 | ABC123     | 17        |
| 01/17/2014 | 01:00 | HEY567     | 28        |
| 01/17/2014 | 01:30 | ABC123     | 17        |
| 01/17/2014 | 01:30 | HEY567     | 28        |
+------------+-------+------------+-----------+
```

How can I **sum 2 rows (Number)** with the same **CUSTOM_ID** & **DATE** and when the given time is only :30 minutes of difference round it to :00 and delete the :30? It should look like this in the end:

```
+------------+-------+------------+-----------+
| date       | time  | custom_id  | Number    |
+------------+-------+------------+-----------+
| 01/17/2014 | 00:00 | ABC123     | 32        |
| 01/17/2014 | 00:00 | HEY567     | 53        |
| 01/17/2014 | 01:00 | ABC123     | 34        |
| 01/17/2014 | 01:00 | HEY567     | 56        |
+------------+-------+------------+-----------+
```

How can I accomplish this with PHP or possibly with a MySQL query?

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc529/1

Comment: Can you provide sqlfiddle, so we could test the solution?

Comment: Sure I will create it right now

Comment: Here is the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb8efb/1

Comment: it would be better if you put different dates into the example

Comment: why date is varchar and not date? And time is also varchar and not time?

Comment: @user4035 Agree, here it is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc529/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT date, MIN(time) as time, custom_id, SUM(Number) as Number
FROM table
GROUP BY date, custom_id, HOUR(time)
```

Comment: WOW. I'm amazed how simple it is, THANKS ALOT you just saved my job! here's the final result if someone else needs it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/913b4/1